# Gaming black-lit keyboards - do they work on ubuntu?

Tags: 13.04, keyboard

I am planning to buy gaming keyboards with back-lit illumination, [specifically the Saitek K140](http://www.saitek.com/manuals/K140_slimline_Keyboard.pdf).

However, I'm confused whether the black-lit illumination, or the multimedia shortcut keys work with Ubuntu (13.04, specifically) .

So, the question is... Do black-lit gaming keyboards work with Ubuntu?

If you would be so kind to review the **Saitek K140 slimline keyboard** specifically that would be much appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The manual you linked indicates that the back lighting control is hardware based and controllable on the keyboard itself. This means that the back lighting would work and be customisable regardless of operating system.

The multimedia keys on the other hand will be dependant on the operating system to determine that they have been pressed and this may require further configuration to make them work.